# Singularize method not found

Tags: c#, sqlkata, humanizer

For the last months I didn't had any problem but since few days my application doesn't start.
I've spent many hours trying my best to finally come with this error :

```
System.MissingMethodException : 'Méthode introuvable : 'System.String Humanizer.InflectorExtensions.Singularize(System.String, Boolean)'.'
```

The problem is related with the SQLKata NuGet extension but i don't have any ideas on what to do.
I've made a few tries like :

- Uninstalling and reinstalling the package
- Repair VS
- Rewrite a part of the code that was working before
- Looking on many places to find a solution

Comment: https://github.com/sqlkata/querybuilder/issues/392

Comment: Downgrading packages did the trick thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure your issue is relating to SQLKata and not *Humanizer*?

The inflector method for Singularise is found here on the Humanizer GitHub page documentation.
https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer#inflector-methods

If this is indeed what you are looking for, you should reinstall the Humanizer NuGet or download from their GitHub and add direct to your project.

You can check if the assembly is within your project by checking the bin folder for *Humanizer.dll*

Comment: Actually Humanizer is only a dependency for my SQLKata Execution so it probably is but  even uninstalling and reinstalling didn't do the trick i am still locked.

Comment: If your application was indeed working then I would roll-back any of these dependency packages, such as Humanizer. Based on your error it does look like it's the Humanizer package that may have changed.

Comment: Actually downgrading was the solution but it take me time to find the correct version to align the version and the dependencies. I found the working version of SQLKata that works without Humanizer (1.1.7)

Answer (score 1):

The Humanizer interface was changed in this commit;
https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer/commit/fc887b302773472f889e2908f79d7325229f9929

Which breaks the compatibility with the latest SqlKata (v2.2.0). Downgrading Humanizer to v2.7.9 worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading **both** SqlKata and SqlKata.Execution to version 2.3.2 worked for me.